# SFTP from web service through Cygwin fails

Tags: perl, cygwin, sftp

I have a web page running on Apache which uses a matured set of Perl files for monitoring our workplace servers and applications. One of those tests goes through Cygwin´s SFTP, list files there and assess them.

The problem I have is with SFTP itself - when I run part of test either manually from cmd as `D:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "/usr/bin/sftp -oIdentityFile=[privateKeyPath] -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -b /cygdrive/d/WD/temp/list_SFTP.sh [user]@[hostname]"` or invoke the **very same set** of Perl files as web it works OK (returns list of files as it should). When exactly same code is run through web page it fails quick and does not tell anything. Only thing I have is error code 255 and "Connection closed". No error stream, no verbose output, nothing, no matter what way to capture any error I have used.

Answer (score 1):

To cut long story short, the culprit was HOME path.

When run manually either directly from cmd or through Perl, the `D:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "env"` would report HOME as `HOME=/cygdrive/c/Users/[username]/` **BUT** this same command when run through web page reports `HOME=/` i.e. root, apparently loosing the home somewhere along the path.

With this knowledge the solution is simple: prepend SFTP command with proper home path (e.g. `D:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "export HOME=/cygdrive/c/Users/%USERNAME%/ ; /usr/bin/sftp -oIdentityFile=[privateKeyPath] -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -b /cygdrive/d/WD/temp/list_SFTP.sh [user]@[hostname]"`) and you are good to go.

Comment: Your description of the problem doesn't have that many details, but it sounds like you are running a web server and asking it thing. Typically, a web server does not run as a normal user, and the user it does use will not have a home directory set, or have the interactive login environment of a user.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in what I do, but the most puzzling thing (at least for me) was when I was running the same commands through the same Perl-program (under same user - not specified in question to keep it simple) one through web and once through cmd and got so different results.

Comment: As I said, the interactive session user and the web user are different. That's why you get different results.